# MySQL Store Procedure Parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, inout

I am currently working on MySQL stored procedures and I am fairly new to these.

When do we need to use `OUT` parameter? With `IN` alone then having only `SELECT` statement at the bottom, the results will also be returned without having to call `@OUT` parameters.

I just need some light here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx):

> **IN –** is the default mode. When you define an IN parameter in a stored procedure, the calling program has to pass an argument to the
>   stored procedure. In addition, the value of an IN parameter is
>   protected. It means that even the value of the IN parameter is changed
>   inside the stored procedure, its original value is retained after the
>   stored procedure ends. In other words, the stored procedure only works
>   on the copy of the IN parameter.
>
> **OUT –** the value of an OUT parameter can be changed inside the stored procedure and its new value is passed back to the calling
>   program. Notice that the stored procedure cannot access the initial
>   value of the OUT parameter when it starts.